# Javascript overriding parents get method

Tags: javascript, arrays, inheritance, overriding

```
// Garbage collection friendly list.
class GCFList extends Array {
  size;

  constructor(initSize = 0) {
    super(initSize);
    this.size = initSize;
  }
  push(content){
    this[this.size] = content;
    this.size++;
  }
  pop(){
    this.size--;
    let returnContent = this[this.size];
    this[this.size] = null;
    return returnContent;
  }
  get length(){
    return this.size;
  }
  set length(newLength){

  }
}

var l = new GCFList();
l.push(2);
l.pop();
console.log(l.length);
console.log("Expecting 0, but getting 1");
```

I'm making a garbage collection friendly array list. I want to use it as a normal array. When I try to override the length getter method, it seems like it is still accessing the parents (Array) length. How do I make it so when I call l.length, I get the size of l?

Comment: Builtin arrays are pretty GC-friendly already. What makes you think you can improve this?

Comment: `length` of arrays is "special" (in the way many JS things are...) What specifically are you trying to accomplish here? What advantage will this have over a standard array? I don't see anything of value yet.

Comment: Where are you running your code? Chrome? Firefox? Transpiled JS?

Comment: @TheWitness Why would it matter? AFAIK they'll implement `Array` in pretty much the same way.

Comment: @Bergi I'm making a game in Javascript. The size of the arrays change radically. If I first increase the size of the array to an enormous size, and then to 0, I worry the list will first reserve a lot of heap memory it then will release. Released heap memory will then build up and cause spike lag when the garbage collector does its collection.

In my approach, the list would only increase in reserved memory but never decrease, causing heap memory reservation and freeing only to occur in the beginning of the program.

Comment: @TheWitness I run the code in Chrome.

Comment: Another possible design choice is to build your own class which uses array as implementation detail.

Comment: @DaveNewton, Chrome versus Firefox should make no difference, you are right here. But transpiled code behaves differently, especially if it rewrites to constructor function (it fails to fails when called without `new`). Also, TypeScript messes up extending native Array due to some run-time versus compilation-time aspects. It does matter.

Comment: @TheWitness Do you mean to have my class contain an array as a property?
BTW, I see that I can set properties dynamically to my class even without the "extends Array". The line "this[this.size] = content;" still works. But I'm not sure if it is bad performance wise. Doing so also allow me to use my own length getter.

Comment: @MarkusFjellheim I would not worry there. Heap memory won't build up, since it's the same array always, and there won't be a big GC hit. I would recommend to start with plain arrays, worry later and measure whether there is an actual GC problem before building a `GcfList`.

Comment: @MarkusFjellheim, if you're interested then I can describe my the idea in the answer. Comment is not good for longer pieces.

Comment: But I agree with @Bergi: optimisation should be a consequence of profiling, not codewise tricks. I have been recently implementing linked list in JavaScript and in the end I came up with conclusion that JS' array is the most powerful collection this language can offer.

Comment: @TheWitness Me implementing this is the result of profiling. See https://i.stack.imgur.com/3k9Jz.png. I was creating a lot of objects and removing references. When I started re-using objects, the performance got a lot better. I haven't checked if the GCFList has an impact yet, but I think it could be difficult to check, since the heap build up is something that require a lot of objects to be deleted before any significant difference could be detected.

Comment: @Bergi It is the same array, but as the size increase I would think at some point the memory would have to be re-allocated to a larger area. I don't know how this works for Javascript and it sounds reasonable the memory would be released immediately instead of queueing it for the garbage collector. If so, my GCFList would be obsolete.

Comment: @TheWitness I would be interested to see.

Comment: @Bergi I did some more profiling. https://ibb.co/BcgkSmW. Here I create an array list and push 100 million elements to it. Then I pop them and repeat. It seems the garbage collector is only active when the list is first built up. The result from GCFList has similar profiling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot overwrite the `.length` behaviour of an array. It is not a getter/setter (even though it behaves like one), and it is not inherited from `Array.prototype`. Each array instance has its own `.length` data property, which shadows your getter/setter on `GCFList.prototype`.

Answer (score 2):

Aside from the problem that you can't really be much more efficient then JS Array (they're sparse etc), you're extending Array, and array's `length` property is not configurable:

```
Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(l, 'length')
// {value: 1, writable: true, enumerable: false, configurable: false}
```

Means, [you can't change that property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty).

Answer (score 0):

*(The solution below is indirectly connected to the question but at the same time it was too long to be posted in comment.)*

As you experienced, extending Array might be problematic. It’s probably the best collection JavaScript has to offer but on its own. What I want to suggest is following:

*(Yes, I believe that structure you’re looking for in your question is stack.)*

```
class Stack {
    constructor(size) {
        this.size = size;
        this.head = -1;
        this.stack = Array.from({ length: size }, () => undefined);
    }

    push(item) {
        if (this.head + 1 == this.size) {
            // if you prefer, this might silently fail but I chose to be explicit
            throw new Error('Stack full!'); 
        }

        this.head += 1;
        this.stack[this.head] = value;

        return this; // so it can be chained and `this.push(1).push(2)` will be possible
    }

    pop() {
        if (this.head == -1) {
            // if you prefer, this might silently fail but I chose to be explicit
            throw new Error('Stack empty!'); 
        }


        const popped = this.stack[this.head];
        // this is theoretically optional but in case of objects we’ll get rid of reference, 
        // hence allowing for garbage collection
        this.stack[this.head] = undefined; 
        this.head -= 1;
        return popped;
    }

    get length() {
        // I put this here as it was in your example 
        // but either having `lenght` property or reading from `string` is actually enough
        return this.size;
    }

    set length(size) {
        if (size > this.size) {
            for (let i = this.size; i < size; i++) {
                this.stack.push(undefined);
            }
        } else if (size < this.size) {
            if (this.head > size) {
                this.head = size - 1; // set it at the end of shorter stack if head would be oustide
            }
            for (let i = this.size; i > size; i--) {
                this.stack.pop();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This gives you “an array” with fixed length and will fail if you try to extend it. I read somewhere that for purposes of games arrays that don’t change their length work better. And in any case, you did your profiling already. Also, because of that I’m not gonna suggest using immutable structure, as this would be heavier on memory.

Possible method you might need also is `peek` that allows to see the current value without popping it.

This is proof of concept that I just wrote so it might need some tweaking, if you decided to go with it, but this is what I had in mind.

Because this means to be fast, I dropped some overly defensive measures, like checking if `size` sent to constructor is a number. I assume it will be for more internal use so you will take care of it.

Comment: Thanks. I think I will use this approach. If I want to access elements that is not at the end using peek() or pop() I could also make a get function get(index){return this.stack[i];} which is used as "myList.get(2)" to get the element at index 2. I Suppose it would not be possible to access it using "myList[2]".